# Which application components can possibly be an entry point in an Android app?

Tags: android

The Android Developer Guide states that  "Application components are the essential building blocks of an Android application. Each component is a different point through which the system can enter your application. Not all components are actual entry points for the user and some depend on each other". I want to know, apart from activity which other components (service, broadcast receiver) can act as an entry point to an Android app. I am sure ContentProvider does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know, apart from activity which other components (service, broadcast receiver) can act as an entry point to an Android app

A `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver` can be an "entry point to an Android app" if they are exported.

> I am sure ContentProvider does not make sense in this context.

I disagree. I would consider an exported `ContentProvider` to also be an "entry point to an Android app".

Comment: Ok. And we can invoke all three through intents once they are exported ?

Comment: @takesavy: A `ContentProvider` is accessed through a `ContentResolver` (directly or indirectly). Services and broadcast receivers are accessed via `Intent` messages.

Comment: @CommonsWare what do you mean by "exported"? I don't understand, can you please help me with it?

Comment: @ChinkySight: "Exported" means that the manifest entry (e.g., `<service>`) has `android:exported="true"`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am new to Android development and I did understand how activity makes entry point to an app as activity is just a screen.  But I am having difficulty understanding how other components (**Services, Broadcast receivers, and content providers**) makes entry point for an app. Can you please explain it with examples? I have done googling, but it was of no help.

Comment: @ChinkySight: If a third-party app starts a service, sends a broadcast (that your app responds to), or works with your provider, the code for that service, receiver, or provider will run. This means that Android will fork a process for your app, to allow that code to run. An "entry point", as described in the documentation, boils down to "causes Android to fork a process for your app". Perhaps you are using a different definition of "entry point".

Answer (score 1):

You may also read [this paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/l/long/download/CHEX_CCS12.pdf) (published in a top security conference, CCS 2012). The authors propose an algorithm to discover possible entry points from an application.